# How do I set the value of an attribute with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, authentication, jwt, thymeleaf

I'm working on an email template that will receive a *confirmationUrl* parameter that's inside an auth method called sendVerificationToken.

HTML

```
<p>Use <a th:attr="href=#{confirmationUrl}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">this link</a> to activate your account now.&nbsp;</span></p>
```

sendVerificationToken method

```
public void sendVerificationToken(User user) {
    String token = jwtTokenService.genEmailVerificationToken(user.getId());
    logger.info("Sending verification token to user. user={} email={} token={}",
            user.getId(), user.getEmail(), token);
    String confirmationUrl = null;
    try {
        confirmationUrl = new URIBuilder(verifyEmailUrl)
                .addParameter(VERIFY_EMAIL_ENDPOINT_PARAM, token)
                .build().toString();
    }

    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("URL stored as redirect url for verify email is not valid.");
        throw ErrorFactory.serverError("Error");
    }
    emailService.sendAccountConfirmationEmail(user.getEmail(), confirmationUrl);
}
```

How do I correctly get the parameter from the method into the HTML template using thymeleaf?

Comment: you bind it to the model int he controller right, like `model.addAttribute("confirmationUrl", confirmationUrl);`

Comment: but how do I create this model param? Does it need to be binded somewhere? @CholNhial

Comment: Yep in the controller params. e.g. `public String editReview(Model model, @PathVariable Long movieReviewId) {...`

Comment: Is there a way around this? I would like to keep the controller params untouched

Comment: Look into ModelAndView, it will keep the controller params untouched because you just return it from the method.

Comment: Thank you for your help, ModelAndView seems like an appropriate alternative indeed, but the HTML template is still not able to find the parameter from the controller.